# Spring Integration DSL - CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler

Tags: lambda, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am writing the sample code for basic-amqp example (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml) in DSL

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow receiveGreetingFromGreetingQueueToConsole(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "greeting.queue"))
            .log()
            .<String,String>transform(m -> "Received " + m)
            .handle(CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler.stdout())
            .get();

}
```

How do I apply the setShouldAppendNewLine boolean on the

```
.handle(CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler.stdout())
```

I don't want to declare the handler as a bean only to set this property. Wish stdout accepted a parameter for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a bean...

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow receiveGreetingFromGreetingQueueToConsole(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler stdout = CharacterStreamWritingMessageHandler.stdout();
    stdout.setShouldAppendNewLine(true);
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "greeting.queue"))
            .log()
            .<String,String>transform(m -> "Received " + m)
            .handle(stdout)
            .get();

}
```

However, I agree that a fluent API would be nice for the DSL to use; please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you ! Issue created - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3343